# Possible canonical question: Windows Active Directory naming best practices?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, canonical

Despite knowing squat about Windows, I have *already this morning* VTC'ed two questions as duplicates of [Windows Active Directory naming best practices?](https://serverfault.com/questions/76715/windows-active-directory-naming-best-practices)  Is it time to elevate that question to full canonicality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, please.

I have that Q&A "starred" and regularly use it as a duplicate and in [comments](https://serverfault.com/q/811816/37681) to point out that people made their bed and now must lie in it...